# should i fill browser key and android key both?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-api-console

I Have coded an app finds nearby places.
 now i want to test it on a real phone but Google map does not load and app not working. my question is I've made sha1 key and put in android key in API console.
do i have to do the same for browser key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no need for Browser key in Android app.

Make sure your Package name matches your SHA-1 Certificate fingerprint in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com) under API & auth -> Credentials-> Android API Key

Comment: it is matche and i did put in android API and get the google key post it in my manifest code. but still not working....